# floating issue on different resolution

Tags: html, css

What is the key reason to go bottom next to left floated div on different resolution.

**From:**

```
+------------+     +-----------------------------+
| float: left|     |     float: right            |
+------------+     +-----------------------------+
```

**To:**

```
+------------+
| float: left|
+------------+
                   +-----------------------------+
                   |     float: right            |
                   +-----------------------------+
```

How to solve this that would be layed in a same position on any resolution?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gR6Ug/)**  CTRL+MOUSE SCROLL UP/DOWN TO SEE CHANGES

Please note I would like to fix it in pixels not in percentage of the width specified.

I can also fix it by setting padding left to right floated element or padding right to left floated element by zero. But why is it behaving differently in smaller or larger resolution?

Comment: Pretty hard to say without seeing the HTML/CSS.

Comment: The "ctrl+mouse scroll" should have been a big clue that this was related to width!  ;)

Comment: When you say "different resolution" you probably are thinking about the window/viewport width...

Answer (score 1):

The total width of the two elements is greater than the total available width.  It is more like:

From:

```
+------------+     +-----------------------------+
| float: left|     |     float: right            |
+------------+     +-----------------------------+
```

To: (notice the overlap)

```
+------------+
| float: left|
+------------+
             +-----------------------------+
             |     float: right            |
             +-----------------------------+
```

It may not look like they overlap, but if you factor in padding and margin, they do.  If you set the widths to percentages, it should work.

Comment: You beat me by seconds to an answer! Rather than post a competing identical answer, I thought it might be useful to post this fiddle I created (http://jsfiddle.net/N5CY2/) to illustrate your point.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give width in percentage and give "float:right" and "margin-top:-500px" to right portion

Please note: I have only give you an example ,you can set "margin-top" as per your need but it must be nagative.

**Update**

You can use center tag.
here is the example

```
<center>
<div style="width:800px">
 <div style="float:left; width:300px"></div> /*give width to adjust to both*/
 <div style="float:Right; width:500px"></div>
</div>
</center>
```

if your screen resolution changes it will stick to the center whatever your screen is big or small

suppose my scree width is 1000px then you can set width to left div 300px and for right div will be 500px

try it....

Comment: Giving Percentage value fix the problem but I would like to know is there any solution with keeping it in pixels that right floated element don't go below.